# How to redirect to the same page without duplicating it when going back in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

In one page I have a form that on submit sends data to an action. This action, when finished with its logic, redirects to the same page. The problem is that when I go back in the browser there is a duplicate page. I want to achieve an action like refreshing.

I tried changing the redirect to `RedirectToActionPermanent()` and `Redirect()`. Also tried disabling the cache once in the action and once in **Program.cs**.

```
[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
```

---

```
Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
Response.Headers["Expires"] = "0";
```

---

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
    context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
    context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "0";

    await next();
});
```

Comment: If the goal is to stay on the same page, perhaps a better approach overall would be to use AJAX to submit the data instead of loading a new page context?

Comment: @David I have to work with the database in the action, can you do that using AJAX?

Comment: How the client makes the request to the server doesn't change whether or not the server-side code can perform server-side operations (such as interacting with a database).  So, yes, when you use AJAX to make a request to the server, the server can execute its code.

Comment: I'll look into it and post an answer when I figure it out the code.